# When using Javascript, Jquery with event handler, how could it be known 'event is event'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Following codes work well. Whenever I click on an item, It opens or closes. But the `event` valuable has some strange behavior to a newbie.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.target demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>item 1
    <ul>
      <li>sub item 1-a</li>
      <li>sub item 1-b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item 2
    <ul>
      <li>sub item 2-a</li>
      <li>sub item 2-b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
function handler( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
    target.children().toggle();
  }
}
$( "ul" ).click( handler ).find( "ul" ).hide();
</script>
```

At the first time, I think event as a variable declared from "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-10.2.js"

So I changed the name of 'event' to 'xxx', and tested.

```
function handler( xxx) {
  var target = $( xxx.target );
  if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
    target.children().toggle();
  }
}
$( "ul" ).click( handler ).find( "ul" ).hide();
```

But It also works well and makes no error.

Finally, I changed codes like this.

```
function handler( xxx ) {
  var target = $( xxx.target );
  var target2 = $( ppp.target );

  if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
    target.children().toggle();
  }
}
$( "ul" ).click( handler ).find( "ul" ).hide();
```

But It makes `Uncaught ReferenceError: ppp is not defined`.
So I'm wondering how and where the `event` or `xxx` variables come from.
And I also want to know how javascript interpreter translate 'xxx' as a function which has `target` property.

Comment: Notice, that the values of the arguments are defined when you're calling a function, not when defining a function.

Comment: The function is called by the Browser API when the event occurs with an argument of `event`. You take the argument to any variable, it will contain the native event that browser provided.

Comment: the first (and only) argument to an event handler is the event, it doesn't have to be called event, it can be called graham

Comment: The name comes from the **parameter declaration** in `function handler( xxx ) {`. And of course you can use anything you want.

Comment: Does the brower API have some  logic like 'new - ready - waiting - running - terminate' of Operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handler` is a function that you pass as callback to other function.

This `handler` function has the parameter `event`, `xxx` or however **you** define it. The `handler` function is then at a later point called with some argument.

```
// this function will accept another function as argument
// this callback will then be called after 1 second, that function is called
// using an object as first argument
function callInOneSecond(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback({
      traget: 'something'
    })
  }, 1000);
}


// it does not matter how the first parameter is called, it will always 
// hold the first argument that is passed to it when "handler" is called.
function handler(xxx) {
  console.log('was called');
  console.dir(xxx);
}

callInOneSecond(handler);
```

Comment: If underthing of mine is ture, In this example, 'later points' repeats over and over in 1second interval , and my example click invoke handler function!

Comment: @jong-hyunYeo `setTimeout` is not `setInterval`. Apart from the fact that `callInOneSecond` uses a timeout to call the function, the mechanism behind it is identical to what a browser does at events, except that the function is called after a timeout and not after a certain event.